# Combining components to one library

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im currently creating a UI library for my react native project.
The components are separated into its own files like: Button, TextBox, Panel etc etc

So when i want to use them I do:

```
import Button from '../UI/button';
import TextBox from '../UI/textBox';
```

But how could I impletement the following call instead? Not needing to do import statetments for each specific component.

```
import { Button,TextBox, SomeOtherComp } from '../UI/??';
```

This would save a lot of typing when I want to use multiple components...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called `index.js`

The purpose of this file is to simple expose all available components from your library

```
import Button from './button';
import TextBox from './textBox';
...

module.exports = {
  Button,
  TextBox,
  ...
};
```

In the code that consumes your UI library, you can now import the components like this:

```
import { Button, TextBox, SomeOtherComp } from '../UI';
```

When you import a folder name, the packages will look for an `index.js` file and import that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to re-export modules directly without writing duplicate code for importing and exporting:

```
// UI.js

export { default as Button } from './button';
export { default as TextBox } from './textBox';
```

Usage:

```
import { Button, TextBox } from './UI';
```